# rails 4 multiple models in one form including a key value table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms, form-helpers

I have a form that creates a "talent profile". In this form as a separate model are attributes "height, weight, hair, etc." for the talent profile. However, there are actually 4 tables involved in this.

Tables with examples
**talent_profile**
id - 1

**talent_profile_attributes -**(links the talent to an attribute with a value)
talent_id - 1
 
default_attribute_id - 2
default_attribute_value_id - 3

**default_attributes -**
id - 2
  name - "hair"

**default_atrribute_values -**
id - 3
  default_attribute_id - 2
  value - "brown"

The relationships with the models are fine, I can insert into the table manually and retrieve the attributes for each profile as desired. However, the problem I am having is figuring out how to submit both the TalentProfile model, and the TalentProfileAttributes model in a single form.

I tried using accepts_nested_attributes_for, but have been unsuccessful. In addition I'm not quite sure how to approach getting the default_attribute_id and default_attribute_value_id into the fields of the form. Any ideas, or directions to go would be greatly appreciated, been researching this for a couple hours now to no avail.

Basically Im looking for a form that displays all the values from the DefaultAttributes table, with dropdowns including the DefaultAttributeValue for each attribute, and when submitted, creates the relationships in the TalentProfileAttribute table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, used this in the model, view and controller

Model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :talent_profile_attributes
```

controller

```
def new
  @talent = TalentProfile.new
  @attributes = DefaultAttribute.all
  @attributes.count.times { @talent.talent_profile_attributes.build }
end
```

View

```
<% attr_i = DefaultAttribute.first.id - 1 %>
<%= f.fields_for :talent_profile_attributes do |attrf| %>
  <%= attrf.label :default_attribute_value_id, @attributes[attr_i].name %>
  <%= attrf.select :default_attribute_value_id, 
                  @attributes[attr_i].default_attribute_values.collect {|p| [ p.value, p.id ] }.unshift("-") %> 
  <%= attrf.hidden_field :default_attribute_id, value: @attributes[attr_i].id %>
  <% attr_i += 1 %>
<% end %>
```